# How to show string message on label of parent User control in C#?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have many User controls in my application. Among which some are parent control of others.Every User control has labels for show messages.I want to write a function which is some thing like below:

```
public void ShowMessageInParent(UserControl control,string msg)
        { 
            //get 1st parent control and show message on its label.                   
        }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: 1. Get parent control from the given control and access label controls Text property to set the required text. 2. you may need to have some way to someway to access parent's label control which would be private by default. Introduce a method in parent control which takes string or make label control public.

Comment: Is this web, wpf, or winform?

Comment: The best approach depends on what type of message you want to show. Is this in an event handler in the child usercontrol i would suggest to use a custom event that you can raise in the child and handle in the parent. On that way you prevent hard-linking the usercontrols so that they are still reusable and work without being nested in each other. Note that the parent is normally the controller and can access it's childs directly, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Its asp.net Usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for WPF or WinForms - as you stated too late that you're talking about ASP.NET:

I'd create an event `StatusMessageChanged` with a corresponding class derived from `EventArgs`. If the message is to be changed, call the event. If the parent control has attached to the event, it can evaluate the arguments and show the message.

```
public class StatusMessageChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public StatusMessageChangedEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public event<StatusMessageChangedEventArgs> StatusMessageChanged;

protected void OnStatusMessageChanged(string message)
{
    if (StatusMessageChanged != null)
        StatusMessageChanged(this, new StatusMessageChangedEventArgs(message));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote a CustomUserControl witch has a label control inside it.

If so you should use

```
control.Parent.Controls.Find("Label", false);
```

Comment: I am working on asp.net UserControls. Each UserControl has different other asp.net controls according to requirement.

Comment: Whould you please post some codes, Any codes? By witch we could understand some more details about your situation